# Google like dropdown search populated from database in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, textbox, dropdownbox

I am looking for a simple but effective way to create a drop down search box  which should work like the google search and is populated by values from a database which acts when I type anything in the textbox. I Should be able to select any of the values. I am looking for the simplest solution and do not want to use a web service or the ajax control toolkit like every example I have seen does. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: If you want to pick data from database without full postback and don't want to use webservice or ajax, I am not sure it would be possible. Keeping eyes on your question if someone answer to this

Comment: How can you fetch record from db with out ajax async request. You need to use ajax or jquery for it.

Comment: @SainPradeep Do you know of any simple examples of using jquery to search the data from the database that might help? On a slight timeline and haven't much time to spend on this task. Thanks

Comment: @Frank Without spending time you want the code ?? This is `STACKOVERFLOW` and not readymade code tutorials website.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like JQuery's Autocomplete, found here:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

If you don't want to use an AJAX query to do the search, you can include all data in your HTML if you want. I wouldn't advise it though, as that information is also publicly visible for your visitors if they take a look at your source. If that's not a problem, then by all means, take this route.

If you do want to load the data via AJAX, the Autocomplete I linked to can also work against a remote datasource. The documentation for that is here:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Example without using a remote datasource (no ajax):

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

In this example you would have to think of a way to print all of your tags into the HTML above, because you obviously cannot hardcode this. How to do this, depends on the technology you're running on. (MVC, WebForms, ...). But you would generally just get all the tags from the database, and print them out into the javascript. Post back if you need an example of this and tell me your technology, and I'll update my answer.

example of remote datasource (with ajax):

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/api/GetValuesForAutocomplete", //the url to query 
  minLength: 2 //the amount of letters the user has to type before the search begins
});

 //in your HTML you would have: 
<input id="birds" />
```

You'll find more complete examples on their website. The URL that you'll have to use for such an ajax query depends on what technology your website is written in. Do you have access to a WEB API project? Or is it an MVC website? Or a Webforms website?

Comment: SO tagged asp.net not php, don't want to call webservice either

Comment: True. I updated my answer somewhat and added some extra explanation about what the URL can be.

Comment: Won't it call webservice?

Comment: Updated my answer again to include an example without using a webservice.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin: can you explain how to do without webservice or ajax, and page not to be postback ?

Comment: No, but SO asked for that. He strictly mentioned that. see the question @Satindersingh

Comment: @Satinder: my first example, without a remote datasource should do what you want then ...

Comment: @StevenLemmens but how will you get `availableTags ` from database?

Comment: You would print them out on the page itself. if it's an ASPX page for example, you can get the tags in code behind and print them out. That's the only way I see if no ajax can be used. This way also doesn't need a postback.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin have saw OP question and understand that he don't want to spend time on this task he not even posted any code that what he tried ?, he want direct a Big Piece of cake in his mouth

Comment: @StevenLemmens: +1 you did it write